# How to make a matrix out of a polynomial equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a system of equations which I need to calculate eigenvalues for but I know how to do get the eigenvalues but my problem is that I don't know how to put this particular system into a matrix.

The system is as follows:
$\frac{dx}{dt}=y$ $\quad$, $\quad$ $\frac{dy}{dt}=x-x^{3}-y$

This is my representation of the matrix. I know this has to be wrong. But I going to keep playing with this.

The point of the question is to calculate the real number in complex eigenvalues to find the behavior of the solutions.

$$
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    -1 & -1 & 0 & -1
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$

I had a question like this before where the system was

$\frac{dx}{dt}=4x-7y-1$ $\quad$, $\quad$ $\frac{dy}{dt}=3x+6x-12$

The matrix was

$$
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    4 & -7 \\
    3 & 6
    \end{bmatrix} 
$$
 The real component of the complex eigenvalue was 5. Leading me to find that the portrait was a spiral source.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to compute the stationary points of this system of ODE. Then compute the Jacobian of the system function at these points. This is the matrix you are looking for.

Comment: I have learned nothing about partial derivatives in my ODE class. Im thinking maybe separate the polynomial into two linear equations?

Comment: Im starting to think that matrices are not needed here. I can say from the computer program that the origin is a source and the point $(1,0)$, $(-1,0)$ are sinks

Comment: And exactly that you can compute from the linearizations at the stationary points.

Comment: can you elaborate please?